# <p:galleria><p:graphicImage> doesn't show the desired images

Tags: image, jsf, primefaces, galleria

I'd like to create an image gallery using JSF, so I tried the PrimeFaces `<p:galleria>`.

The backing bean `galley.java`:

```
@ManagedBean
public class galley {
private List<String>list;
@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    list=new ArrayList<String>();
    File file=new File("/home/user/Pictures/wallpaper/batman");
    File[]fList=file.listFiles();
    for (File f:fList){
        if (f.getName().endsWith("jpg"))
            list.add(f.getAbsolutePath());
    }
}

public List<String> getList() {
    return list;
    }
}
```

The view `gallery.xhtml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<p:galleria value="#{galley.list}" var="image" panelWidth="500"  panelHeight="313" showCaption="true">
<p:graphicImage value="#{image}" alt="Image Description for #{image}" title="#{image}"/>
</p:galleria>
</html>
```

The result:

[image]

As you see, the images don't show up. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

---

**EDIT**:

now my resources folder is like this :

[image]

and my `gallery.xhtml` is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    >
 <h:head>
   <title>gallery</title>
 </h:head>
 <h:body>
    <p:galleria value="#{galley.list}" var="image" panelWidth="500" panelHeight="313" showCaption="true">
    <p:graphicImage value="resources/images/#{image}" alt="Image Description for #{image}" title="#{image}"/>
</p:galleria>
</h:body>
```

but it gives me `null pointer exception` on `for (File f:fList)`

Comment: `Value` attribute takes `Binary data to stream or context relative path` according to `Primefaces` documentation not the absolute path to the image.

Comment: thanks @SRy, even `/home/user/Pictures/wallpaper/batman/#{image}` dose not work

Comment: Why don't you just follow the `Primefaces showcase` to achieve this simple requirement. http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/galleria.jsf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i wanted to accept @BalusC answer but i don't know why he deleted the answer

as you can see in the edited part , the `.xhtml` format was wrong (the true .xhtml part is in edited part)

and also the resources folder was wrong that it corrected in edited part

thank you  @BalusC